# Pandas Filtering one dataframe if a value is between two values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as follows:

df1

```
  chr_number      start        end strand
0       chr1  111478338  111478339      +
1       chr1  111478370  111478371      +
2       chr1  111478372  111478373      +
3       chr1  157123306  157123307      -
4       chr1  157123307  157123308      -
5       chr1  212619741  212619742      +
6       chr1  212619742  212619743      +
```

df2

```
  Chromosome      Start        End  Log2 Fold Change Strand      Gene  \
0       chr1  111478330  111478444          3.036912      +  C1orf162   
1       chr1  157123300  157123338          3.293174      -      ETV3   
2       chr1  207079296  207079412          3.916122      +    PFKFB2   
3       chr1  212619736  212619771          3.880546      +      ATF3   

           Ensembl ID Feature  
0  ENSG00000143110.11  3' UTR  
1  ENSG00000117036.12  3' UTR  
2  ENSG00000123836.15  3' UTR  
3  ENSG00000162772.17  3' UTR
```

I need to look if start from df1 is located between Start and End in df2. If so, I'd like to have a new data frame which contains start value from df1 with corresponding row in df2.

Here is the example of what I need for each start value from df1:

```
   CrossLink Chromosome        Start          End  Log2 Fold Change Strand  \
1  111478338       chr1  111478330.0  111478444.0          3.036912      +   

       Gene          Ensembl ID Feature  
1  C1orf162  ENSG00000143110.11  3' UTR
```

I wrote this code:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([])
df3["CrossLink"] = np.nan
for v in df1["start"]:
    df4 = df2[(df2["Start"] <= v) & (df2["End"] > v)]
    df3 = df3.append(df4)
    df3["CrossLink"] = df1["start"]
```

And I get this output:

```
   CrossLink Chromosome        Start          End  Log2 Fold Change Strand  \
0  111478338       chr1  111478330.0  111478444.0          3.036912      +   
0  111478338       chr1  111478330.0  111478444.0          3.036912      +   
0  111478338       chr1  111478330.0  111478444.0          3.036912      +   
1  111478370       chr1  157123300.0  157123338.0          3.293174      -   
1  111478370       chr1  157123300.0  157123338.0          3.293174      -   
3  157123306       chr1  212619736.0  212619771.0          3.880546      +   
3  157123306       chr1  212619736.0  212619771.0          3.880546      +   

       Gene          Ensembl ID Feature  
0  C1orf162  ENSG00000143110.11  3' UTR  
0  C1orf162  ENSG00000143110.11  3' UTR  
0  C1orf162  ENSG00000143110.11  3' UTR  
1      ETV3  ENSG00000117036.12  3' UTR  
1      ETV3  ENSG00000117036.12  3' UTR  
3      ATF3  ENSG00000162772.17  3' UTR  
3      ATF3  ENSG00000162772.17  3' UTR
```

It does not contain all my start values from df1 and it gives me duplicates. I am quite new in python and pandas and I searched a lot but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the id of rows in two dataframes is like each other? For example, is the second row in the first dataframe corresponding to the second row in the second dataframe?

Comment: Unfortuntely no. They are independent data frames and I posted here as a small sample.  The original data is much more bigger and came from different sources. But df1 do not contain Log2 Fold Change information. That is why I have to filter it by using df2. I try to compare first line of start column to Start and End in all df2 and then second line of search column to all df2 again and it goes on like that.

Comment: Is `df2.start <= df1.start <= df2.end` the only thing that matters here?

Comment: kindly share the dataframes as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict('records')``. Your current form is hard to copy/reproduce

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a two step process:

Let's say we have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chr_number':['chr1', 'chr2'], 'start':[3, 5],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['chr1', 'chr3'], 'col': ['a', 'b'], 'start': [1, 2], 'end':[4, 5]})

print(df)
print(df2)

  chr_number  start
0       chr1      3
1       chr2      5
  index col  start  end
0  chr1   a      1    4
1  chr3   b      2    5
```

We can then apply aggregation and explode to get the desired output.

```
df2.start = df2.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(x['start'] <= df.start) & (df.start <= x['end'])].start.agg(list), axis=1)
print(df2.explode('start'))

  index col start  end
0  chr1   a     3    4
1  chr3   b     3    5
1  chr3   b     5    5
```

Edit: I realized that I was doing the incorrect operation comparing `df2` values instead of `df`. The edited code now replaces `df2.start` with all `df.start` values that fall between `df2.start` and `df2.end` for rows of `df2`.